# Compare date between two dates using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

this is my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>

<products>
    <product_id value=" 1 ">
        <tab_id value=" 51 ">
            <tab_name value=" test1 "/>
            <status value=" 2 "/>
            <log value=" 5748 , 5749 , 128 "/>
            <born_from value=" 1980-08-01 , 1989-02-01 "/>
            <born_to value=" 1985-08-01 , 1998-02-01 "/>
            <sex value=" 2 , 1 "/>
            <link value=" www.google.com "/>
        </tab_id>
    </product_id>
    <product_id value=" 2 ">
        <tab_id value=" 52 ">
            <tab_name value=" test2 "/>
            <status value=" 3 "/>
            <log value=" 458 , 912 , 333 "/>
            <registration value=" 2013-01-01 "/>
            <born_from value=" 1995-01-25 , 1993-08-03 "/>
            <born_to value=" 2000-01-25 , 2002-10-25 "/>
            <sex value=" 1 , 1 "/>
            <link value=" www.yahoo.com "/>
            <label value=" open "/>
        </tab_id>
    </product_id>
    <product_id value=" 3 ">
        <tab_id value=" 54 ">
            <tab_name value=" test3 "/>
            <status value=" start "/>
            <venue value=" US "/>
            <born_from value=" 2000-01-01 , 2002-02-01 "/>
            <born_to value=" 2005-01-01 , 2003-01-01 "/>
            <sex value=" 1 , 2 "/>
            <link value=" www.facebook.com "/>
        </tab_id>
    </product_id>
 </products>
```

i have written this XSLT code  to display all the data of product where the `my_date` variable will compare between to dates of born_from and born_to and give the output data of product 1 & 2

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:param name="my_date" select="'1992-01-01'"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="/products" priority="1">
        <html>
            <body>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product ID</th>
                        <th colspan="2">Product DATA</th>
                    </tr>
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="product_id/tab_id/born_from[@value &gt; $my_date] | product_id/tab_id/born_to[@value &lt; $my_date]"/>
                </table>
            </body>
        </html>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product_id/tab_id">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <xsl:value-of select="product_id"/>
            </td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name(*[1])"/> --></td> 
            <td><xsl:value-of select="*[1]/*[1]"/></td>
        </tr>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(self::product_id)]"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!--These 2 templates will handle the data on the same
    row as the tab name.-->
    <xsl:template match="product_id/tab_id/*[1]" priority="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates mode="newrow"/>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="product_id/tab_id/*[1]/*[1]" mode="newrow"/>

    <xsl:template match="*" mode="newrow">
        <xsl:call-template name="dataRow"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="product_id/tab_id/*/*[not(position()=1)]">
        <xsl:call-template name="dataRow"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="dataRow">
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td/>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
        </tr>       
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="*[not(self::node)]">
        <tr>
            <td/>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="name()"/> --></td>
            <td><xsl:apply-templates/></td>
        </tr>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

i am beginner to date comparison there is something wrong

simply `my_date` will compare like this

```
 for product 1
1980-08-01 > my_date && my_date < 1985-08-01
1989-02-01 > my_date && my_date < 1998-02-01

 for product 2 
1995-01-25 > my_date && my_date < 2000-01-25
1993-08-03 > my_date && my_date < 2002-10-25

same for product 3
```

here `my_date` compare with both first value then secound and so on.. i think here issue is comma separated values

i want my output like this

```
Product ID  |   Product DATA
--------------------------------
1           |product_id  => 1
            |tab_id      => 51
            |tab_name    => test1
            |status      => 2
            |log         => 72
            |               19
            |               79
            |born_from   => 1980-08-01
            |               1989-02-01
            |born_to     => 1985-08-01
            |               1998-02-01
            |sex         => 2
            |               1
            |link        => www.google.com
```

same for the product 2 with its value
thanks in advance

Comment: XSLT 1.0!! Oh there isn't any inbuilt method!

Comment: also xslt 1.0 doesn't support DateTime datatype! Which IDE/SDK are you using? I can help you accordingly..

Comment: @infantPro 'Arvind' i dont know abot it i am beginner to XML and XSLT

Comment: I meant to ask, which tool you use for development and implementation?

Comment: @infantPro 'Arvind' i am using PHP

Comment: @Tony Shih i am using | for `And` operation

Comment: sorry I deleted my question as I noted it later.

Comment: strangely I cannot even get any matching nodes let alone wrong nodes :) I will try

Answer (score 3):

Before talking about dates, it should be noted there is another issue with your **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="product_id/tab_id/born_from[@value &gt; $my_date]" />
```

This will select **born_from** elements, but from looking at your matching templates it looks like you want to actually select the **tab_id** element, so you would have to re-write it like so:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="product_id/tab_id[born_from/@value &gt; $my_date]" />
```

However, as mentioned in the comment there is no in-built support for dates in XSLT 1.0. You would either have to use an exension function or upgrade to use XSLT 2.0.

However, if your dates are always going to be in YYYY-MM-DD format, you could do simple numeric comparison by removing the hyphens and treating them as 8 digit numbers.

First, create a variable to convert your **my_date** parameter into a number of the format YYYYMMDD

```
<xsl:variable name="comp_date" select="translate($my_date, '- ', '')" />
```

Then, try changing the subsequent **xsl:apply-templates** to this.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="
product_id/tab_id[translate(substring-before(born_from/@value, ','), '- ', '') &gt; $comp_date]| 
product_id/tab_id[translate(substring-before(born_to/@value, ','), '- ', '') &lt; $comp_date]"/>
```

Note the use of **substring-before** to extract only the first date before the comma in the **@value** attribute. If you also wanted to check the date after the comma, use **substring-after**.