# Filtering set of rows with XSLT

Tags: xslt

i have troubles filtering with XSLT, basically i have an xml, where i would like to get only those items where the Due Date falls into interval of 3 months ... i've written the following:

```
<xsl:variable name="TaskRows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Tasks/Rows/Row[@DueDate &gt; $IsoBeginQuartDate AND @DueDate &lt; $IsoEndQuartDate]"/>
```

But I get an error: "Failed seting processor stylesheet: expected token ']' found 'NAME' ...

IsoDates are calculated and formated dates in ISO format ...

Any idea, how to do it, or i can't use "AND" when filtering?

PS: i'm using XSLT 1.0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is case-sensitivity at work here! Try using 'and' instead of 'AND'.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately in XSLT 1.0, you can't compare dates to see if a date is between two values.

What you could do is something like this:

```
<!-- Make sure to format this variables as YYYYMMDD -->
<xsl:variable name="$IsoBeginQuartDate">20130101</xsl:variable>
<xsl:variable name="$IsoBeginQuartDate">20131231</xsl:variable>

<!-- Make sure @DueDate also has the format YYYYMMDD, in this example I assume the DueDate has format YYYY-MM-DD -->
<xsl:variable name="TaskRows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Tasks/Rows/Row[translate(@DueDate, '-', '') &gt; $IsoBeginQuartDate and translate(@DueDate, '-', '') &lt; $IsoEndQuartDate]"/>
```

You now get errors, because `&gt;` and `&lt;` or not supported for strings or dates.

Comment: both of them are iso formats already and it is yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ssZ and when i removed AND and just tried to do it with one ... it worked no errors like that <xsl:variable name="TaskRows" select="/dsQueryResponse/Tasks/Rows/Row[@DueDate &gt; $IsoBeginQuartDate]"/> BUT then i get no results at all :(

Comment: See this and more results on Google on selecting between dates and XSLT 1.0: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15217677/compare-date-between-two-dates-using-xslt